# Show cart details on a button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, findcontrol

I want to show my `cart` details on a `Button_Click_Event`. I'm using a Gridview control of ASP.NET framework. But the following exception occurs:

```
object reference is not set to a instance of an object.
```

How can I fix it? Here is my code:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string st = "select * FROM cart_master";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(st, sqlcon);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    GridView GridView1 = (GridView)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView1");
    sda.Fill(ds, "cart_master");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["cart_master"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: what line of code throws the exception

Comment: GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["cart_master"];
line throws a exception @Pleun

Comment: I'm just going to say two things here, bad Architecture, bad Security.

Comment: @No1_Melman i want a error free code ...actually

Comment: I think the error doesn't come from the data source but from the GridView side. `GridView1` is possible null and it is beacause the `FindControl` method call doesn't find the GridView. Please post your markup code

Comment: i think so... @luviktor

Comment: @AnuragDixit I understand you! Sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do. I just feel sorry for the poor fellow who has to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dataset, just fill a datatable from your adapter

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("ResultDataTable");
sda.Fill( dataTable);
GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```